# Autohotkey daily macro doesn't work well

Tags: autohotkey, file-copying

I created a macro in autohotkey that is able to copy at 7:40 a.m. the last file created in a shared disk into a dropbox folder. When I launch the macro to try it, setting the "time to meet" 2 minutes later for example, it works perfectly. The problem is that the day after the macro doesn't start. Could you help me please?

Thanks

Marco

```
SetTimer, Chronos, 59900
Return

Chronos:
FormatTime, TimeToMeet,,HHmm
If TimeToMeet = 740 ; If you wanted the script to start at 7 am put change 1006 to 700
{
run O:\research\
winactivate, research
sleep 1000
MouseClick, left, 289, 586
send {PgDn 6}
clipboard = 
Send ^c
clipwait 
sleep, 1000
FileCopy, %clipboard%,C:\Dropbox\
sleep 2000
winclose research 
return


}
Return
```

Comment: What happens between the two days? Do you shut down your computer?

Comment: I don't shut down the computer, it is always on (no sleep mode) with this macro active.

Comment: There are many things that can go wrong with this approach. One is that you do not check after `run o:\research` if the window is really active (or wait until it is) so there`s no way to know what your clicks are doing. There might be a screensaver on your PC that stops this from working. If I had to get your script to work I would make it write a log file (like this: `fileappend errorlevel:%Errorlevel% time:%A_Now% MoreTextonWhatCommandIJustRan,c:\temp\logfile.txt`), so I could check later what exactly didn't work.

Comment: I didn't think about the screensaver. I try to write a log file as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: The screensaver was blocking the macro. Is there a command that can turn off the screensaver? Thanks for your help

Comment: How about turning it off in the windows settings? If you want to keep the screensaver activated and just prevent it from appearing, you could send an input event every X minutes, e.g. a timer that moves the mouse cursor one pixel. Anyway, your problem seems to be a typical case for [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Unattended user interface automation like this may not be the most reliable aproach.
I would recommend using the Windows Task Scheduler to handle launching the process. I think this might be safer than having the script running 24 / 7 waiting to go. Even more importantly, it looks like you are doing very basic file manipulation by automating the UI. This type of work may be better acomplished with a Windows batch file or Autohotkey's functions for files. Note that batch files are less fussy about screensavers and being logged in. I love AutoHotkey, but that seems to be a weak spot. Check out the documentation for each of the functions that start with the word file. I'd be surprised if you couldn't hook some of those up to do what you need. Since you seem to be looking for a file, check this one out:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm
I think this thread may be of help as it finds the most recent file in a folder:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/57475-open-most-recent-file-date-created-in-a-folder/
Good luck!